# How to close chrome native app made with python?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have made an chrome extension that interacts with a native app made with python. On closing my browser my native app doesn't end. I read somewhere that chrome sends -1 as message before ending. Following is the code I used to receive from extension -

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

def func():
    while True:
        if sys.stdin.read(1) == -1:
            logging.info("inside func got minus one")
            sys.exit()

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
p.start()
```

Comment: maybe save in log what you get from `stdin` to see if it really sends `-1`

Comment: Yes I did but I didn't received -1 even once

Comment: maybe in extension you could send message when it is closed.

Comment: I don't know if there is any listener that listens the browser closing event

Comment: Does your code run `func` asynchronously? The nativeMessaging stdio cycle should be performed synchronously in the main thread, look at any example. As for `-1` it's the correct signal to check.

Comment: I have tried synchronously as well but no luck

Comment: @wOxxOm my native app works as a server between a client and extension such that when client sends an input then only my server starts listening the extension. So, if I try stdin synchronously my code gets stuck there until an output is received from the extension. That's why I tried the asynchronous way to listen for -1 and everything else works smoothly.

Comment: If there's any other code that reads stdin then your `func` won't see -1.

Comment: I use a persistent connection in my extension and once the port it closed, it shuts down my native host, as per the documentation. In your extension, are you using runtime.ConnectNative or runtime.sendNativeMessage? I also looked at the python example provided by Google and I don't see anything about looking for a -1. Have a look here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/host/native-messaging-example-host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging, which includes an example in Python.
You need to read the length of the message. It is a 4 bytes (32 bit) integer. If the length is 0, that is your signal to exit.

```
def func():
    while True:
        text_length_bytes = sys.stdin.read(4)
        if len(text_length_bytes) == 0:
            sys.exit(0)
        # still here, read text_lenth_bytes from stdin
```